# Detect if child GUI is hung from a parent process

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my application there is a parent process that spawns its children.  I am trying to leverage this parent process to watch over the children to ensure that the GUI remains responsive, and if not, generate a dump file.

The problem I'm running into is that `Process.Responding` is only detecting some GUI hangs (such as sleeping on the GUI thread or a stack overflow) but not others (such as deadlocks on the GUI thread).

So the question is: How else can I check whether or not the GUI of the child is still updating from the parent process?

EDIT: Based on the comments so far I guess I should clarify.  I am responsible for maintaining the framework of an application with a plugin architecture that is heavily multi-threaded and has a code base of hundreds of thousands of lines of code, much of which is outside my control.  While I understand that the ideal approach is not to hang in the first place, it still happens on occasion.  I would like these situations gracefully and collect debug information along the way so that the issue can be addressed.

Another approach I've considered is using the GUI thread to touch a file and have the parent process check the time stamp of the file.  However, I'd rather not perform file operations on the GUI thread.

Comment: If you are using multiple threads try to use async and await for processes that are not "Main-Thread" related.

Comment: Why are you running code on the UI thread that can deadlock? It's a bad sign if you have to create a program within your program to monitor if it hangs.

Comment: I always use log4net for the logging. It shows the time stamp and thread number so that you know which process are you staying at. https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/example-apps.html

Comment: Also use baretail for log reading. They are all free. https://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few failed attempts with the strategies I mentioned above, here's how I ended up solving this:

1. At child application start I save a reference to the GUI thread
2. A timer is started that periodically checks the thread state of the
   GUI thread (about every 200ms).  If it is ThreadState.Running, I
   report the process as responding to the parent through
   inter-process communication.
3. In the parent process I keep a dictionary of the process IDs
   and the time the process was last reported as responding.  If a
   child is still alive but hasn't reported a responding result within
   the timeout period, the user is notified that the process is not
   responding.

So far, everything seems to be working as I would expect it to.